# Where do you put the intents in Eclipse

Tags: android-intent

I am new to Developing Android Apps and I was wondering where do I put the Intents at, or where is send message() method. Here's the link to what I'm talking about http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent

Comment: onCreate method in your activity

Answer (score 0):

```
Open the MainActivity class and add the corresponding method:

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
}
```

It's right there in the tutorial